# Does dnscrypt-proxy's configuration replace /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, hosts, dnscrypt-proxy

I've recenly installed `dnscrypt-proxy`. The configuration file for it at `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml` has a blacklist section I'm currently using:

```bsh
[blacklist]

  ## Path to the file of blocking rules (absolute, or relative to the same directory as the executable file)

blacklist_file = '/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/CustomIgnores.txt'
```

I was wondering whether this option replaces the redirects at /etc/hosts? Or that both are used?
What does the /etc/hosts file even belong to? And how does the Blacklist option for dnscrypt even work(I assume it also just redirects to localhost)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making DNS queries, the order of lookup is determined via `Name Service Switch` configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. You can check yours via:

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep -i hosts
```

As an example, it might output the following:

```
hosts: files dns
```

Here `files` refers to local hosts file (`/etc/hosts`) and dns refers to the server specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. The lookup is processed in the order they are written, therefore `/etc/hosts` will be processed first in this case. If the domain name is not found in the file, then it will try the server in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Coming back to your case, if your `nsswitch.conf` file has `files` value before `dns`, and a particular domain is listed both in `/etc/hosts` and `blacklist` entry in `dnscrypt-proxy.toml`, the one in `/etc/hosts` will precede. Also, if a correponding enty does not exists in `/etc/hosts`, but in dnscrypt-proxy `blacklist`, it will result in `refused` response. Quoting from dnscrypt-proxy GitHub wiki page:

> blacklists: names, or patterns that will cause a query to immediately receive a REFUSED response.

References:

- https://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf
- https://nambirajeshblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/difference-between-etchosts-vs-etcresolv-conf-in-linux/
- https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Filters

Comment: Very helpful indeed, and answers most of my question. Thanks